# How to download a single file from local BitBucket server using cURL or wget, not cloning the repo

Tags: linux, download, wget, curl, bitbucket.org

I am trying to download a single file from BitBucket on the linux server.  I do have access to the repositories when I try to access it from the web, so it is not permissions issue

I used to be able to use this command

```
curl --output <output-file-name>  -u <userid>  http://bbserver:7990/projects/prjname/repos/repponame/browse/configurations/infile.txt
```

Now, when I tried to execute it, it just downloads an html page

I also tried the below command using the raw path.  This also downloads an html page

```
curl --output  outputfile.txt  -u <userId> http://bbserver:7990/projects/prjname/repos/repponame/raw/configurations/infile.txt?at=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster
```

I also tried the wget command - but same output.

What do I need to modify or look at ( or ask help from the linux SA to look at ) to be able to download the single file?

Also, can I download the directory - like `configurations` above instead of a single file.

Of course, I need to get the download of single file working to be able to go to the next step.

I have searched SO, but these are the commands I found to download a file from BB.  Didn't find a solution for what to do when it returns an html file

Thank you

Comment: Is it not possible anymore?  I also tried replacing -u <userid>  with "Authorization: Basic <bas64_uid:pwd>"  and also Personal Access Token with Bearer for authorization  -  but get the same result.  What is confusing is I used to be able to do it before and do not know what has changed.  Hopefully, someone has an answer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's an API path that you can use

```
curl -u user:pwd http://bitbucket:7990/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJCT_NAME/repos/REPO_NAME/raw/FOLDER/FILE.TXT
```

If nothing else, the API response will be something more usable than the HTML response.
API documentation at

https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.18.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idp366

Comment: If you pass -u user without a password it will prompt you, if you don't want the password in history. Adding -o file.txt will put the content on disk rather than to the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe better to use git directly as bitbucket seems to be "trying to prevent" this functionality.

git archive --format=tar 
--remote=ssh://remote_server/remote_repository master path1/ path2/ | tar -xv

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Comment: Why the 'raw' view would serve html is mind-numbingly stupid. The cynical side of me starts to wonder if Atlassian is trying to knee-cap this functionality to sell some other solution... but then, what's Atlassian's solution? Maybe they are just inept? :-)